# Internal Override with MOQ base method gets called regardless

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

```
public class StuffToTest
{
    //do something..
    internal string MethodToBeTested()
    {
        //do something..
        string result = MethodWithFileOpenAction(new List<string>(), new List<string>());
        return result;
    }

    internal virtual string MethodWithFileOpenAction(List<string> text1, List<string> text2)
    {
        string text = OpenFile();
        //do something..
        return text;
    }

    internal string OpenFile()
    {
        return "Example string base Method";
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        string input = "Example string not base Method";

        Mock<StuffToTest> mockedObject = new Mock<StuffToTest>();
        mockedObject.Setup(item => item.MethodWithFileOpenAction(
                    It.IsAny<List<string>>(),
                    It.IsAny<List<string>>()))
                    .Returns(input);

        //Added after answer was provided, problem still persists
        mockedObject.CallBase = true;

        string result = mockedObject.Object.MethodToBeTested();

        Assert.AreEqual("Example string not base Method", result);
    }
}
```

Edit:
To reproduce my issue, you can either put both classes in one Project which creates a dll for NUnit, or you can put the classes in seperate projects. If you seperate them you need to add [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject1")] to AssemblyInfo.cs. And change the Project name if necessary.

---

Running the test, I would like to avoid the OpenFile() operation, which is why I override the method in the Test. Now when I call the test, it still calls the base method with the file open operation.

Did I do anything wrong?

---

Edit 2:
Changing the internal modifier on the virtual method to public fixes the problem of calling the base method instead of the overriden one. I would like to avoid changing the modifier to public in my original project if possible. Any suggestions why internal blocks the override while access is granted via `InternalsVisibleTo` would be appreciated.

Comment: that doesn't happen means.. did it go into that method (which has open file operation) ? or it didn't return proper mock response ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code. This code wouldn't compile for various reasons, making it really hard to work out what's going on.

Comment: yeah it calls the base method instead of the moq one

Comment: I didn't add a code example at first since I didn't have enough time and I thought the issue would be something trivial I simply overlooked. Apparently I was mistaken

Comment: It's still not a [mcve]. What is `Resources.OpenFileContentCopy`? For a truly minimal example, we should be able to just copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: But your example is trying to mock out `MethodToBeTested` instead of `MethodWithFileOpenAction` for one thing.

Comment: question is fixed

Comment: With the modification, the code already works - although the fact that you've changed the question to include the suggestion in my answer makes my answer look stupid, which is quite rude.

Comment: I added your suggested answer into my question because it didn't fix it, I fixed it by accident by changing the types to public to make it a more easy to use example for you. The other Project is the original one where I still have the problem. I will change my question to point out that the callback was added afterwards and specify the persisting problem.

Comment: The code you've given will throw an exception due to a lack of expressing `InternalsVisibleTo` for the Moq generated assembly. At least, it does for me. If it doesn't for you, please specify the exact version of .NET you're targeting, and the exact version of Moq you're using. (Note that this is also the documented behavior for Moq, so it's not at all surprising.)

Comment: I mentioned the need to add the InternalsVisibleTo part in the question, in case you don't have both classes in the same project. Of course the exception gets thrown if you don't have it. The exception isn't the issue though

Comment: No, you've missed the point. It's not `InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject1")` - it's `InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")`, because that's the generated proxy assembly. And that exception is the *first* part of the problem, where `CallBase` is the second part of the problem. With both pieces in place, all should be fine, and that explains everything I've seen when running it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176063/discussion-between-sirechicken-and-daisy-shipton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock internal types, you need to use `InternalsVisibleTo` so that Moq is able to generate subclasses and override appropriately. See the [moq user guide](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for details - search for "mocking internal types". Basically you need to add something like:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

... but potentially with a public key as well.

At that point, it should work fine because your `MethodToBeTested` is non-virtual. If you changed `MethodToBeTested` to be virtual, you would need to tell Moq to call any methods that haven't been otherwise set up to be mocked:

```
Mock<Foo> mock = new Mock<Foo>(param) { CallBase = true };
```

That way when you call `CallSomeMethod`, it will execute the regular method, and only use the mocked method for `ReturnMethod`.

Comment: I already tried that. It didn't have any impact on how the test worked.

I used mock.CallBase = true; shouldn't make a difference though

Comment: @SireChicken: Once you've posted a [mcve], I'll look into it further.

Comment: copy & paste example with your solution, if I debug it while running the test and put a break point in the MethodWithFileOpenAction, the break point triggers.

Comment: @SireChicken: Trying to run that code, I get: "Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Cannot set up StuffToTest.MethodWithFileOpenAction because it is not accessible to the proxy generator used by Moq". That's fixed by using `InternalsVisibleTo` as described in the documentation - at which point it works fine. (It doesn't stop in `MethodWithFileOpenAction`.)

Comment: did you change the modifier from internal to public?

Comment: @SireChicken: No, I fixed it with `InternalsVisibleTo`, as described in the documentation. But changing everything to be public works too, as you've done in your question now. That all works fine.

Comment: I was running the test with both parts in the same class, I didn't need the InternalVisibleTo markup. I was using that in the other project since it was needed there. But I still had the issue. The test in the minimal example is running without the Exception for the markup when I use internal

Comment: @SireChicken: It shouldn't, and doesn't for me. (I don't know what you mean by "the other project" - please don't assume we have all the context you do.) The reason InternalsVisibleTo is required is because Moq generates a new assembly with the extra code in. Note that your example would be simpler if you used it in a straight console app rather than a unit test app - the simpler you can make the example, the better. (It would also be more complete with using directives - ideally we should be able to copy/paste/compile/run.)